# This SQL select statement uses index seek but the index seek is not helping . I updated stats still run long how to improve this query

Tags: sql-server, performance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJjIs.png)  **How to  improve this select  query imagine i have index on where clause** 
returns

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    'mamo', c.ClientID
FROM 
    mamo.dbo.Client c 
INNER JOIN 
    mamo.dbo.Vehicle v ON v.ClientID = c.ClientID
LEFT JOIN 
    mamo.dbo.EventLog el ON el.VehicleID = v.VehicleID
INNER JOIN 
    la.dbo.Client c2 ON c2.ClientID = c.ClientID 
LEFT JOIN 
    la.dbo.Vehicle v2 ON v2.ClientID = v.ClientID
WHERE 
    el.[filename] NOT IN (SELECT [FileName] 
                          FROM la.dbo.EventLog 
                          WHERE [FileName] IS NOT NULL)
    OR c2.ModDT < c.ModDT
    OR (v2.VehicleID IS NULL OR v2.ModDT < v.ModDT)
```

Comment: Please show us the **table structure** of those tables involved, tell us what **indexes** you have on those tables, and what kind of data (number of rows) you have in each table involved in this query

Comment: There's no way, you're getting SEEKs on all 5 tables... I'm surprised you're getting a SEEK on any of them. The fact that you are seeing any at all is concerning because there's a possibility that it's seeing every row in the table(s), which is WAY more expensive than a single scan of the table. When you look at the plan, what is the estimated number of executions? and what is the total row count of the table?

Comment: so i'm thinking is  there a better way to rewrite it

Comment: Provide an execution plan (as an attached ,sqlplan file). Execution plans are the first thing you need for query tuning.

Comment: if you remove both the `mamo.dbo.EventLog join` and the `el.[filename] NOT IN` predicate, is there much performance difference?

Comment: yes when i remove WHERE 
    el.[filename] NOT IN (SELECT [FileName] 
                          FROM la.dbo.EventLog 
                          WHERE [FileName] IS NOT NULL)
    OR c2.ModDT < c.ModDT
    OR (v2.VehicleID IS NULL OR v2.ModDT < v.ModDT)  it ranin one sec if i run the whole thing it takes 5 minutes

Comment: when i ran without where clause it's good the problem is when i run with where clause it takes 5 minutes

Comment: Any one can give suggestion on the where clause part? thanks